# which should be used: array vs linked list?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I am planning to implement a bounded queue without using the `Queue<T>` class. After reading pros and cons of `Arrays` and `LinkedList<T>`, I am leaning more towards using Array to implement queue functionality. The collection will be fixed size. I just want to add and remove items from the queue.

something like

```
public class BoundedQueue<T>
{
   private T[] queue;
   int queueSize;

   public BoundedQueue(int size)
   {
      this.queueSize = size;
      queue = new T[size + 1];
   }
}
```

instead of

```
public class BoundedQueue<T>
{
   private LinkedList<T> queue;
   int queueSize;

   public BoundedQueue(int size)
   {
      this.queueSize = size;
      queue = new LinkedList<T>();
   }
}
```

I have selected Array because of efficiency and due to the fact that collection is fixed size. Would like to get other opinions on this. Thanks.

Comment: Classic case of speed vs. efficiency. Array will be faster for the computer, but a LinkedList will most likely require fewer lines of code. The decision is truly up to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should of course use a `Queue<T>`, but in the question you said that you don't want to use queue and instead implement the queue yourself. You need to consider first your use case for this class. If you want to implement something quickly you can use a `LinkedList<T>` but for a general purpose library you would want something faster.

You can see how it is implemented in .NET by using .NET Reflector. These are the fields it has:

```
private T[] _array;
private const int _DefaultCapacity = 4;
private static T[] _emptyArray;
private const int _GrowFactor = 200;
private int _head;
private const int _MinimumGrow = 4;
private const int _ShrinkThreshold = 0x20;
private int _size;
[NonSerialized]
private object _syncRoot;
private int _tail;
private int _version;
```

As you can see it uses an array. It is also quite complicated with many fields concerned with how the array should be resized. Even if you are implementing a bounded array you would want to allow that the array can be larger than the capacity to avoid constantly moving items in memory.

Regarding thread safety, neither type offers any guarantees. For example in the documentation for `LinkedList<T>` it says this:

> This type is not thread safe. If the LinkedList needs to be accessed by multiple threads, you will need to implement their own synchronization mechanism.

Comment: How does setting it's capacity use less memory?  It's doing the same thing (reserving the memory).

Comment: @Mark: Any thoughts from multi-threading perspective? Will it be same in both the cases?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: Both methods are not thread safe unless you explicitly use synchronization. There are some thread safe containers in .NET 4.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. Any idea if .net class Queue<T> has been implemented using Array or LinkedList<T>?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: Yes, you can see that in .NET Reflector. It's an array of T.

Comment: The .Net `Queue<T>` class is implemented with an array. If you're looking for multithread use, consider using the net `ConcurrentQueue` class.

Comment: @Mark: Regarding "However relying on the IndexOutOfRangeException for your code to work correctly is bad style". Can't we just check if array is full or empty before enqueuing or dequeing an item? I didnt get the point behind relying on IndexOutOfRangeException. Can you pls. explain it a bit more?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: 
"Can't we just check if array is full or empty before enqueuing or dequeing an item?" Yes you should do that. "I didnt get the point behind relying on IndexOutOfRangeException.": The point was that you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Am I missing something? I wasn't aware an `ArrayList<T>` class existed in .NET.

Comment: @Mark: Wait, so how is `List<T>` an appropriate backing store for a *queue* implementation? Wouldn't the OP have to call `RemoveAt(0)` for `Dequeue` operations; and wouldn't this be far less efficient than the way `Queue<T>` does it? I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting, but I can't figure out how a bounded queue implemented using a `List<T>` makes sense.

Comment: @Dan Tao: You're right and I guess my answer didn't really answer the question anyway - not sure why it was accepted. I have tried to answer the question now, though my interpretation of the question appears to be quite different from yours.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it would be a mistake.  I'm going to guess your are a former C/C++ programmer, std::list is king.  On the surface, it is incredibly frugal with memory, can't make a list possibly more efficient than only allocating the memory you need, right?  Yes, LinkedList does that.

But no, it is incredibly incompatible with the way CPU caches work, they *really* like arrays and hate pointers.  Put the garbage collector on top of that, so quite capable of packing memory.

The read-them-and-weep benchmarks [are here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24206/A-look-at-STL-CLR-performance-for-linear-container).  Stark.

Comment: Sadly, the link has died. Here's the last I could find on [web archive:](http://web.archive.org/web/20110701000000*/http://www.voidnish.com/Articles/ShowArticle.aspx?code=StlClrBclComparison)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd rule out using a `Queue<T>` internally, especially considering you're up for using a `LinkedList<T>` (they're in the same assembly). A `Queue<T>` would give you the greatest performance and memory usage. Your class could look something like this:

```
public class BoundedQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> _queue;
    private int _maxSize;

    public BoundedQueue(int maxSize)
    {
        if (maxSize <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxSize");

        _queue = new Queue<T>(maxSize);
        _maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _queue.Count; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new item to the queue and, if the queue is at its
    /// maximum capacity, also removes the oldest item
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// True if an item was dequeued during this operation;
    /// otherwise, false
    /// </returns>
    public bool EnqueueDequeue(T value, out T dequeued)
    {
        dequeued = default(T);
        bool dequeueOccurred = false;

        if (_queue.Count == _maxSize)
        {
            dequeued = _queue.Dequeue();
            dequeueOccurred = true;
        }

        _queue.Enqueue(value);

        return dequeueOccurred;
    }
}
```

But maybe you had a good reason for ruling out the `Queue<T>` class that I just can't think of?

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use LinkedList<T> either :) But just to see time taken between Array and LinkedList<T> implementations I used it. I found Array implementation to be faster. If LinkedList<T> was faster I would have implemented it without using out of the box .net class. Hope that explains my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array, you just have to keep count of the index of the head element, or move everything down by one each time you add something.  Arrays are good for accessing by an index, linked lists are good for next/previous and fast insertion.

for instance, if you have [1,2,3,4,5], and the head is 1, you add 6, you'd drop 5 off the back I guess and put six in its place.  6 would be the new head, but the contents of the array would be [1,2,3,4,6].

Answer (score 0):

So here are the main difference/avantages/disavantages of using both arrays and linked-lists:

Arrays:
- Adding items to arrays can be relatively costly if the insertion is not made at the end (as well as deleting) because all the array elements have to be moved.
- Very efficient if object are added at the end
- Access to the elements is very fast... Simply point to the adress!

LinkedList:
- Adding elements anywhere in the queue is always the same cost in time, and is very fast
- Accessing the elements has to be done with an accessor (iterator).

So your trying to implement a queue... but what kind of queue?
 It all depends on what you will do with it.

If your implementing First In First Out (or Last In Last Out) queue (like a stack), you are better off using a Linked-List, since you can always use the same accessor to access the front or back-end of your list.

But if you want a queue and have to constantly access your elements at different places, go for the array!

From what I understood of your task, I would have recommended a Linked List... but you will know best!

This will only be a problem if you start having ALOT of elements in your queue. If you stay below the few thousands, it doesn

hope it helps

Comment: Its a bounded queue with FIFO.

Comment: since it's bounded, you can add things without moving everything down.  Just keep track of the head index, and figure out the true index of any element by adding head + index and using modulo.

Answer (score 0):

How will your bounded queue behave when an element is added beyond its capacity?  Will the first item be pushed out like this `[1, 2, 3] -> [2, 3, 4]` or will the last item be replaced like this `[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 2, 4]`?  If the former, then I'd recommend a LinkedList.  If the latter, an array or List<T> is fine.  I just thought I'd ask since the behavior of your object will determine the appropriate course of action, and that behavior was never defined as far as I can tell.  Maybe everyone but me just already knows exactly what you meant by a "bounded queue", but I didn't want to assume.

Comment: Beyond capacity it will throw queuefullexception.