# Chain linked classes

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

I have created long chains of classes, with each link(class) knowing only the next and previous link.
I see great advantage over Arrays when the index is not important.

```
public class ChainLink
{
    public ChainLink previousLink, nextLink;

    // Accessors here
}
```

Questions :

1. What is this technique actually called? (I don't know what to search)
2. Is there a .Net class that does the same thing?
3. Is there a noticeable performance impact vs. Array or List?

---

### Example of the Accessors I use

Assign to the chain :

```
    public ChainLink NextLink {
        get{ return _nextLink;}
        set {
            _nextLink = value;
            if (value != null)
                value._previousLink = this;
        }
    }

    public void InsertNext (ChainLink link)
    {
        link.NextLink = _nextLink;
        link.PreviousLink = this;
    }
```

Shortening the chain :

If I un-assign the next link of a chain, leaving the remaining links un-referenced by the main program, the garbage collector will dispose of the data for me.

Testing circular referencing :

```
    public bool IsCircular ()
    {
        ChainLink link = this;
        while (link != null) {
            link = link._nextLink;
            if (link == this)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Offset index :

```
    public ChainLink this [int offset] {
        get {
            if (offset > 0 && _nextLink != null)
                return _nextLink [offset - 1];
            if (offset < 0 && _previousLink != null)
                return _previousLink [offset + 1];
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe something like a double linked list?

Comment: LinkedList<T> should fulfill your needs as a double linked list (has .First and .Last properties). Items in there are of type LinkedListNode<T>, which have .Previous and .Next properties

Comment: Have you tried LinkedList<T>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) This structure is called a double linked list

2) This implementation exists in C# through [LinkedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx)

3) There is a lot of articles on this topic :
[here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/) or
[this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273589/which-should-be-used-array-vs-linked-list)

Comment: Thanks this helped. This however uses LinkedListNodes (Similar to my class) and the LinkedList acts like some kind of grouping class.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the question about what this is called and the equivalent .Net class (a `LinkedList`), but I thought I'd quickly look at the speed of your `ChainLink` vs an array and a `List`.

I added a method `Foo()` to your `ChainLink` class so that there was something to access for each object instance:

```
public class ChainLink
{
    public ChainLink previousLink, nextLink;

    // Accessors here
    public void Foo()
    { }
}
```

The first method creates an array and then times how long it takes to access each item in the array:

```
private void TestArray()
{
    // Setup the Array
    ChainLink[] Test = new ChainLink[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        Test[i] = new ChainLink();

    // Use a Stopwatch to measure time
    Stopwatch SW;
    SW = new Stopwatch();
    SW.Start();

    // Go through items in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < Test.Length; i++)
        Test[i].Foo();

    // Stop timer and report results
    SW.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(SW.Elapsed);
}
```

Next, I created a method to use a `List<T>` and time how long it takes to access each item in it:

```
private void TestList()
{
    // Setup the list
    List<ChainLink> Test = new List<ChainLink>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        Test.Add(new ChainLink());

    // Use a Stopwatch to measure time
    Stopwatch SW;
    SW = new Stopwatch();
    SW.Start();

    // Go through items in the list
    for (int i = 0; i < Test.Count; i++)
        Test[i].Foo();

    // Stop timer and report results
    SW.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(SW.Elapsed);
}
```

Finally, I created a method to use your `ChainLink` and move through the next item until there are no more:

```
private void TestChainLink()
{
    // Setup the linked list
    ChainLink Test = new ChainLink();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        Test.nextLink = new ChainLink();
        Test = Test.nextLink;
    }

    // Use a Stopwatch to measure time
    Stopwatch SW;
    SW = new Stopwatch();
    SW.Start();

    // Go through items in the linked list
    while (Test != null)
    {
        Test.Foo();
        Test = Test.nextLink;
    }

    // Stop timer and report results
    SW.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(SW.Elapsed);
}
```

Running each of these yields some revealing results:

> TestArray():      00:00:00.0058576
>
> TestList():       00:00:00.0103650
>
> TestChainLink():  00:00:00.0000014

Multiple iterations reveal similar figures.

In conclusion, your `ChainLink` is about 4,100 times faster than an array, and about 7,400 times faster than a `List`.

Comment: Thanks. This test helps allot. I tried your script myself and got to similar results.

Comment: I then tested LinkedListNode giving a result similar to that of the Array.